# Azure Cognitive Search: Possible to search for null-valued fields when field is searchable but NOT filterable?

Tags: azure, full-text-search, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

### Description:

Is it possible to search for null-valued fields if they don't have the "Filterable" checkbox enabled on the schema in Azure Cognitive Search?

Example Schema:

```
field1: Complex
  field1/subfield1: String --- Retrievable & Searchable (NOT Filterable)
  ...
```

Example Document1:

```json
{
  "field1": null
}
```

Example Document2:

```json
{
  "field1": {
    "subfield1": null
  }
}
```

It seems like you could do a filter operation like `$filter=field1/subfield1 ne null`, but that's only possible if the field is marked as Filterable on the schema definition.

Note: Rebuilding the schema with the field as Filterable is not a viable option for my scenario, unfortunately.

### What I've tried:

I was hoping that something like "the field doesn't start with any alphanumeric character" would work:

```
search=field1/subfield1: (NOT /a.*/) AND field1/subfield1: (NOT /b.*/) AND ...&$queryType=full&$searchMode=all
```

Or the field doesn't match an any-string regex:

```
search=field1/subfield1: (NOT /.*/)&$queryType=full&$searchMode=all
```

Another thing that could solve this is if you can negate an *entire* search query (i.e. find all documents that don't satisfy these constraints), but I haven't been able to figure out if that's possible either.

### EDIT: Semi-Solution!

If you are lucky enough to have another Searchable field that's *always* non-null, you can do something like the following!

```
search=(alwaysNonNullSearchableField: /.*/ AND NOT field1/subfield1: /.*/)&$queryType=full&$searchMode=all
```

For some reason, Azure Cognitive Search doesn't let you do just a `NOT` search clause...

**Still curious if anyone has a solution without relying on another non-null Searchable field.**

Comment: Note: `NOT field: /.*/` will match both null values and empty-string values for that field